# R: access element in a column of lists with data.table

Tags: r, arrays, list, data.table

I'm using data.table to store a big array of objects, and I want to access one of those objects, but it always returns the result wrapped in a list.

```
library(data.table)

a1 = hist(1:10)
a2 = hist(2:11)
a3 = hist(3:12)
a4 = hist(4:13)
a5 = hist(5:14)
a6 = hist(6:15)

a = list(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
i = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
j = c(1,2,3,1,2,3)

dt = data.table(i = i, j = j, a = a)
class(dt[i == 1 & j == 1, a]) # hist inside a list of length 1
```

I'd like the previous line to return to object itself (just the histogram), like this:

```
class(a1) # just the hist
```

Obviously I could do:

```
dt[i == 1 & j == 1, a][[1]]
```

But it seems inelegant to do that every time. Any way to achieve this using syntax within data.table? Note: there is another question with a very similar name, but it's asking something more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yours is the only way, or similarly I would do `dt[i == 1 & j == 1, a[[1]] ]`.

You could write a helper function like

```
get_a = function(ii,jj) dt[.(ii,jj), on=.(i,j), mult="first", a[[1]]]
```

but might regret it if you ever write a subset that matches 0 or 2+ rows of the table:

```
get_a(1,1)   # works as expected
get_a(1,4)   # returns NULL
get_a(1,1:2) # returns only (1,1)
```

If you want to avoid that, could add checks based on `.N`...

```
get_listcol = function(..., d, list_col, join_cols = names(list(...)), mult = FALSE){
  d[list(...), on=join_cols, nomatch=0, {
    if (.N == 0L){
      stop("No matches found.")
    } else if (.N == 1L){
      .SD[[1]][[1]]
    } else {
      if (mult){
        .SD[[1]]
      } else {
        stop("Multiple matches found.")
      }
    }
  }, .SDcols=list_col]
}

# usage
get_a2 = function(ii, jj) get_listcol(i = ii, j = jj, d = dt, list_col = "a")
get_a2(1,1)   # works as expected
get_a2(1,4)   # error
get_a2(1,1:2) # error
```

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't address the root issue, a matrix of `hist` objects seems to be more in line with the MRE.

```
mat = matrix(a, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

mat[1, 2]
##would result in list

mat[1, 2][[1]]
```